# React call to Flask endpoint is being redirected from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: reactjs, flask

I'm sending a request from my React app to my Flask backend. The problem is that the request is being changed from HTTPS to HTTP.

I've tried adding this code in app.py, but it just results in a redirect loop and the error below.

```
    @app.before_request
def before_request():
    # avoid preflight redirects
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        return jsonify({"status": "success"}), 200

    # if not preflight request and not HTTPS redirect to HTTPS
    HTTPS_ENDPOINTS = ['/register']
    if request.path in HTTPS_ENDPOINTS:
        if request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') == 'http':
            url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
            code = 301
            return redirect(url, code=code)
```

Here's the error:

```
GET https://example.com/register net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

This error only happens on my prod server which runs on Heroku. Other endpoints work, but this one does not. Any ideas?

If I remove the code above, I get this error. Note that there's nowhere in my code where I call the HTTP URL listed in the error--that's coming from a redirect.

```
    Mixed Content: The page at 'https://herokuapp.org/dashboard' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://example.com/register/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Flask will automatically redirect a path like `/register/` to `/register` with 308 status. In my Flask server, I created a blueprint like this:

```
user = Blueprint('register', __name__)
```

And then I was starting my `/register` endpoint like this:

```
@user.route('/', methods=["POST", "OPTIONS"])
```

I didn't realize, I had created the path `/register/` which Flask treated as a 308 and automatically redirected to the HTTP path `/register`.

Wow